# Move blogs but with applied filters

Tags: php, migration, blog

I have to move blogs from a WordPress site to another WordPress site but with applied filters.

**Details:**

Every blog has an author as we all know it but this time when I move the blogs, I only want to tag them in the article rather than showing '**by this_author**'. I have the database, I have migrated the whole site and I'm able to access the site without any problems. The blogs are also visible along with their author name but that's not what I'm trying to do.

I would like to know if there is a way I can remove all the '**posted by this author**' to just their names in the article as a **tag**. I'm working with over 1000+ authors, so I can't take the manual route.

phpMyAdmin
Ubuntu 18.04
php

Comment: You can use WP CLI to write a migration script that can accomplish this.

Comment: is there an article or blog post that I can read to do this?

Comment: Here's a decent example: https://www.toptal.com/wordpress/automating-with-wp-cli

Comment: Hey, I looked at the article and I'm not quit sure how it will help me remove the 'posted by author' with 'tags' as I'm not familiar with writing scripts.

Comment: That's the answer: you're going to have to write some code to accomplish this.